# Easiest way to duplicate array values right after occurence?

Tags: php, arrays

I want these arrays...

```
array('bread','jelly','olive');
array('chocolate','chip');
```

To become these arrays...

```
array('bread','bread','jelly','jelly','olive','olive');
array('chocolate','chocolate','chip','chip');
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Will array('bread','jelly','olive',bread','jelly',''olive'); work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function duplicateItems(array $inputArray, $n = 2) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($inputArray as $value) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$duplicateArray = duplicateItems(array('bread', 'jelly', 'olive'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$myarray = array('bread','jelly','olive');
$mynewarray = array_merge($myarray, $myarray);
sort($mynewarray);
var_dump($mynewarray);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "bread"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "bread"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "jelly"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "jelly"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "olive"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "olive"
}
```

Comment: `array('chocolate','chip');`

Comment: IMO this doesn't answer the OPs question. See my comment above, but basically: a) the performance is poor (you're doing double the work of the basic examples listed below), and b) you're not preserving original sort order by sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_splice()
Works really fast, because no sorting is involved.

```
$a = array('bread','jelly','olive');
$i=0;
foreach ($a as $b) {
    array_splice($a,$i*2,0,$b);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$singleValues = array('bread','jelly','olive');
$newArray = array();
foreach ($singleValues as $value) {
   $newArray[] = $value;
   $newArray[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this will work: array('bread','jelly','olive',bread','jelly',''olive');

```
 $array = array('bread','jelly','olive');
 $array = array_merge($array, $array);
```

Then you could sort alphabetically:

```
 sort($array);
```

Comment: The performance here will be bad on large arrays, and doesn't necessarily preserve original order

Comment: @ColinMorelli yep, which is why my part doesn't sort, even though sort time is only probably O(logN)

Comment: Sort internally uses a modified quicksort which is an O(nlogn) algorithm.